# Html Icon not shown beside title

Tags: html, reactjs, favicon

I have a favicon Logo for a website inside the folder "public/img/". This is the code that I have written:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/img/Logo.png" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

        <!--Google Fonts-->
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
        <link
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=ZCOOL+KuaiLe&display=swap"
            rel="stylesheet"
        />
        <title>React App</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

But favicon is not displayed. Why is it not visible?

Comment: looks like a typo, image path should be relative like `<link rel="icon" href="img/Logo.png" />`

Comment: If you are using relative reference for your image, make sure value of the href attribute is correct.

Comment: I set it like this `img/Logo.png` but no different

Comment: Check out your logo name, is it "Logo.png" or "logo.png"?

Comment: theres no typo on file name & path `img/Logo.png`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to refresh the cache by holding down СTRL + F5. Or test your app with another browser.
If that doesn't help, try this option:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/img/Logo.png" />
```

Comment: i use `CTRL + F5` it nothing different. but i try on different browser it work. I think is just my browser

Comment: @Kofusu Then don't pay attention, the icon actually works, just the cache saved your old icon :)

Comment: after i try to access the png on inspect element, it displayed correctly